# How to setup grunt-contrib-nodeunit to output JUnit xml?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, gruntjs, nodeunit

I can't find any info how to setup reporters in grunt-contrib-nodeunit module, now I have this task in my Gruntfile.js.

```
nodeunit: {
   all: ['nodeunit/**/*.test.js'],
}
```

How to tell grunt to use built-in JUnit report with custom output path?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code you simply can't. However you can use `grunt-shell` do to so:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell');

  grunt.initConfig({
    shell:{
      nodeunit_with_junit:{
        command: './node_modules/nodeunit/bin/nodeunit --reporter junit --output ./junit_ouput tests/*.test.js',
        options:{
          stdout: true,
          stderr: true,
          failOnError:false,
          warnOnError: true
        }
      }
    }
  });

};
```

And run it with `grunt shell:nodeunit_with_junit`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the reporter in the options like so:

```
    nodeunit: {
        client: ['test/unit/client/test*.js'],
        server: ['test/unit/server/test*.js'],
        options: {
            reporter: 'junit',
            reporterOptions: {
                output: '_build'
            }
        }
    },
```